# Php extend method while overriding it

Tags: php, function, class, methods

Is it possible to extend a parent class **method** while overriding it ? For example:

```
class Foo {

    public function edit() {
     $item = [1,2];
     return compact($item);
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    public function edit() {
     // !!! Here, is there any way I could import $item from parent class Foo?
     $item2 = [3,4]; //Here, I added (extended the method with) some more variables
     return compact($item, $item2); // Here I override the return of the parent method.
    }
}
```

The issue is that I cannot edit the `Foo` class in any way as it is a vendor package.

I don't want to edit the vendor methods I need to extend them (add something more to their `return` function)

Comment: Why are you using `compact()`?

Comment: No reason, just for example. It's something like `return view('view-file', compact($item))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you used `array_merge()` instead it will probably show the results better...

```
class Foo {

    public function edit() {
        $item = [1,2];
        return $item;
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    public function edit() {
        $item = parent::edit();  // Call parent method and store returned value
        $item2 = [3,4]; //Here, I added (extended the method with) some more variables
        return array_merge($item, $item2); // Here I override the return of the parent method.
    }
}

$a = new Bar();
print_r($a->edit());
```

This will output -

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
)
```

So the call to `parent::edit()` will return the array from the parent class and this will be added to the array from the second class function.

**Update:**

I can't test this, but hopefully this will give you what your after...

```
class Foo {
    protected function getData() {
        return [1,2];
    }
    public function edit() {
        return return view('view-file', compact($this->getData()));
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    protected function getData() {
        $item = parent::edit();
        $item2 = [3,4];
        return array_merge($item, $item2);
    }

}
```

This means that the only time you create the view is in the base class, all you do is add the extra information in the derived class.

Comment: And if the `return` doesn't only return 1 variable? Or is returning some view together with the variable something like `return view('view-file', compact($item))`.Is it possible if the method is bigger than what I wrote, to just import into the Bar class all the code in the Foo's edit method?

Comment: You can return arrays of objects/views etc.  The main thing is how you deal with the return value.  You may find that it's easier to split it into 2 methods, 1 which assembles the data and another which returns the view.  This allows you to separate the functionality and call it any way you need.

Comment: If `parent::edit()` is returning the result from `return view('view-file', compact($item))`. Can you please tell me how can I insert `$item2` into the `return view('view-file', compact($item, $item2))`. I don't know how can I separate the `parent::edit()` result.

Comment: I've added some new code, give it a go and see if it works as you need.